# Which one is best View or Stored procedure in sql server for data access purpose

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I often use stored procedure for data access purpose but don't know which one is best view or SP.

Stored procedure and views are both compiled and execution plan is saved in database. So please tell me which one is best for data access purpose and why best list down the reason please.

I search google to know which one is best but got no expected answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views and stored procedures serve entirely different purposes.  Views are a convinient way to refer to a complex relational set (such as one that joins across many tables) as a flat table without actually forcing the data to be manifested.  You use a view to clean up SQL code.  Your stored procedures could call views.  Views are often used for permission control.  You can grant a database user access to a view without granting them access to the underlying tables.  This grants the user column level permissions on the columns in the view which is a far more granular method for permission control than granting access to whole tables.

Stored procedures are used to keep often used functionality together as a unit.  To be honest, SPs are falling out of favor among many programmers.  While you are correct that SPs have their execution plans cached, dynamic SQL has had execution plan caching since SQL Server 2000 (I believe that's the correct version).  The only speed gain you're going to get by going with SPs is by sending less data over the network, and that's going to be extremely minimal.  SPs tend to make code more brittle and require changes to the DB to occur when application changes don't really warrant it.  For example, if you just wanted to change the conditions for which rows you're selecting.  Using SPs, you're going to have to roll changes out to the application and the database code.  If you're using dynamic SQL or an ORM tool, you only need to make changes to the application which simplifies deployment.  There is absolutely a time and place for SPs, but they don't need to be your only method for interacting with the database.

Also, if you're worried about performance, you can materialize views which reduces the need to repeatedly query the underlying tables.  This could greatly enhance your performance if you feel the need to add the extra overhead on inserts/updates that materializing views induces.

Answer (score 13):

I disagree with Jared Harding when it comes to stored procedures causing application updates to be more difficult. It's much easier to update a stored procedure than to update application code, which might need to be recompiled and require you to kick users out of the system to make an update. If you write all your SQL in stored procedures, you'll probably only have to update the application half as often as you otherwise would. And a stored procedure can be updated with no disruption to the users.

I strongly recommend use of stored procedures over views or SQL written within application code. With parameterized stored procedures that use dynamic SQL built as a string and called with the secure sp_executesql function, you can write a single stored procedure for selecting data that can be used across multiple applications and reports. There is virtually no need to use a view unless you really need to block permissions on underlying tables. It's much better to create your basic SELECT query inside a stored procedure and then use parameter options to change how the results are filtered. For example, each parameter can add a different line to your WHERE clause. By passing no parameters, you get back the full unfiltered recordset. As soon as you need to filter your results by a different field, you only need to add one parameter and one line of code in that procedure, and then have any application that needs to make use of it pass in the parameter. By defaulting your stored procedure parameters to null, you don't have to change any applications which are calling that stored procedure for other purposes.

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer.  Well done @JediJones

Answer (score 1):

To speed up the query you need properly defined indexes on the table. Within a stored procedure  you can use paramteres, implement  your own logic, however within a view you cannot

Because: Once procedure is compiled it makes its execution plan and use same for every time we call it even when we insert new data in related table as well, untill we make any change in procedure code.

View check for new updated data every time you call it.

You can do whole transaction handling etc with SP.